# Android Geofences stop triggering

Tags: android, geolocation, geofencing, android-geofence

I am using Geofences in my app. I am aware of the 100 Geofences per app limitation.
The way I handle Geofences is:

1. Create the Geofence with NEVER_EXPIRE
2. When the Geofence is triggered, delete the Geofence by the ID
3. Add then re-trigger it after certain time

Everything works fine the first few days, and then suddenly one day every Geofence stops working.

There is no API to check how many Geofences are active.

Appreciate any advice on how I can troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to you to keep track of the geofences. You should keep a list (either in shared preferences or sqlite/room) of the active geofences that you've set and remove old ones when they aren't needed

Comment: Thanks. I am tracking the Geofence requests in a list but somehow it seems the limit is getting exhausted for some reason. I would assume a Geofence with the same ID counts as 1, regardless of how many times I requested and deleted it.